# Induction question?

Tags: induction

I have a problem that is supposed to use induction, but I have no idea how to solve it.  Could I get some help?

The closed form sum of

12 $\left[ 1^2 \cdot 2 + 2^2 \cdot 3 + \ldots + n^2 (n+1) \right]$ for $n \geq 1$ is $n(n+1)(n+2)(an+b)$. Find an + b.

Comment: Is that 12 supposed to be out front?

Comment: Try substituting $n=1$ and $n=2$.  That should give you 2 equations you can solve for a and b.

Answer (score 3):

For determining $a$ and $b$ it's sufficient to use two values of $n$, say $n=1$ and $n=2$. Then verifying the conjecture, that is
$$
12\bigl(1^2\cdot 2+2^2\cdot 3+\dots+n^2(n+1)\bigr)=n(n+1)(n+2)(an+b)
$$
for all $n\ge 1$ (where $a$ and $b$ are those determined before) requires induction. You already have the base case ($n=1$), so you can write
\begin{multline}
12\bigl(1^2\cdot 2+2^2\cdot 3+\dots+n^2(n+1)+(n+1)^2(n+2)\bigr)\\
=n(n+1)(n+2)(an+b)
+12(n+1)^2(n+2)
\end{multline}
and go on from here to obtain the expression
$$
(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(an+a+b)
$$

Comment: I don't quite get it... how do we determine a and b again, before we verify with induction?

Comment: @BobJoe: the answer by Adi Dani explains very explicitly how you can find $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @BobJoe For $n=1$: $12(1^2\cdot 2)=1(1+1))1+2)(a+b)$ or $24=6(a+b)$, that is, $a+b=4$. For $n=2$: $12(1^2\cdot2+2^2\cdot3)=2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot(2a+b)$ or $168=24(2a+b)$ or $2a+b=7$. This easily gives $a=3$ and $b=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is prove (which you probably already have) inductively the formula for the sum of squares and cubes:
$$
1^{2}+\ldots+n^{2} = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\\
1^{3}+\ldots+n^{3} = \frac{n^{2}(n+1)^{2}}{4}
$$

and then note that the sum that you have $(1^{2}2+\ldots+n^{2}(n+1))$ is actually the sum of the first n squares and n cubes. Then, you have:

$$
12(1^{2}2+\ldots+n^{2}(n+1)) = 12(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} + \frac{n^{2}(n+1)^{2}}{4}) \\
=n(n+1)(3n(n+1)+2(2n+1)) = n(n+1)(3n^{2}+7n+2)
$$

So you're missing the factor of $n+2$. To finish then, you just do

$$
(n+2)(an+b)=(3n^{2}+7n+2),
$$

open it up and realize that $a=3$ and $b=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$12\bigl(1^2\cdot 2+2^2\cdot 3+\dots+n^2(n+1)\bigr)=n(n+1)(n+2)(an+b)$$
for $n=1$
$$12\bigl(1^2\cdot 2\bigr)=1(2)(3)(a+b)=6(a+b)=6a+6b$$
$$24=6a+6b$$
$$a+b=4$$
$$b=4-a$$
for $n=2$
$$12\bigl(1^2\cdot 2+2^2\cdot 3\bigr)=2(3)(4)(2a+b)=24(2a+b)=48a+24b$$
$$12\cdot 14=48a+24b$$
$$14=4a+2b$$
$$7=2a+b$$
$$7=2a+4-a=a+4\implies a=3,b=4-3=1$$